# Chrome does not update data attribute of object tag

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I would like to dynamically change the 'data' property of an 'object' tag but this does not work in Chrome 48: in the console I can see the attribute value is updated correctly but the first animation is always displayed. Am I missing something?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.addEventListener("load", function (event)
            {
                setTimeout(function ()
                {
                    console.log("change")
                    document.getElementById("flash").data = "http://edmullen.net/flash/BBC2.swf"
                }, 2000)
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object id="flash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://edmullen.net/flash/BBC2.swf"></object>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tested your code in Chrome 48 and it works fine..

Comment: Works fine for me also..

Comment: Can repro on osX mavericks, chrome 48 : there is a frame drop in swf animation but it doesn't change to the other animation. @ZakariaAcharki, which config did you tested it against ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/33/ you could see that the data attribute change.

Comment: Provide an example please, a jsfiddle or something.

Comment: Actually the attribute itself is updated, but the change is not taken into account: the first animation is always displayed.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki but not the displayed data... There were also bugs with cached content in the `<object>` on webkit, probably related.

Comment: Yes @Kaiido since `anim1.swf` it's not a valid swf link.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki No I mean with real files... If you only tested it with non-existing urls, I see how you didn't saw the bug ;-) Ps : I'm still interested in your config

Comment: It only occurs with swf, svg are well updated, so maybe also something to do with shokwave plugin, mine is 20.0 r0

Comment: @CBroe here is a working example : http://plnkr.co/edit/0K2SHlcp0dVvDnBKMuL0?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce it on my mac os X mavericks with Chrome 48 and Shockwave Flash plugin r20. r0 .

A working example can be found here : http://plnkr.co/edit/0K2SHlcp0dVvDnBKMuL0?p=preview

You may want to fill a bug report to chrome, Canary 50 is also concerned.
It seems to be related with some cache issue webkit had with `<object>` element.

I didn't find a real fix, even setting the data to "" before changing the `data` property doesn't works.

The only workaround I can think of is to replace your element :

```
var obj = document.getElementById('flash');
obj.data = "newUrl.swf";
obj.parentNode.replaceChild(obj.cloneNode(true), obj);
```

Comment: Note that as CBroe said, you'll loose all event listeners attached directly to the element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("flash");
element.setAttribute("data", "anim2.swf");
```

This is obviously an alternative, but your code should be working as is? Anyway try this and let me know how it goes...If it doesn't work then check your console for errors.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki - It shouldn't, but it's an alternative. May aswell give it a shot, if it doesn't work then there must be some unknown error?

Comment: Well then maybe the question should be taken down as the code is working? @ZakariaAcharki

Comment: I can repro it and setAttribute doesn't work either... Note that chrome [had a bug recently](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=568448) with HTMLObjectElement, maybe related...

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Quite possibly could be the issue @Kaiido

Comment: Tried with setAttribute() instead but still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I remember this was problematic in older IE already … changing `object` properties dynamically via script did not get the shown flash to change.

If you can, you could just replace the complete object element with a new one. (*If you can* meaning if there’s nothing else that prevents you from doing so, like any event handlers bound to the element itself, those will get lost. But that can be worked around by using event delegation, instead of binding the event handler to the element directly.)

Can f.e. simply be done by assigning the `outerHTML` of the element to itself again, after the data attribute was changed, see modified version of kaiido’s plnkr, http://plnkr.co/edit/wIFUdI8c29awFujkIkGf?p=preview